# letterSpacing and lineSpacingMultiplier can be declare in style file in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

i am using letterSpacing and lineSpacingMultiplier in XML

```
android:letterSpacing="0.44sp"
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.33"
```

so i need to apply these two attributes in style file.
but I am not able to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `styles.xml` add a style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Text">
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.44</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.33</item>
</style>
```

And in your `TextView`, use this style:

```
<TextView
  style="@style/AppTheme.Text" />
```